# Python If Elif Else conditions

Tags: python

If an item to be purchased costs more than $5000 then the purchaser must go to tender (display a message), if the item costs between $500 and $5000 inclusive then the purchaser must get quotes from three different suppliers (display a message), otherwise the purchaser can just go ahead and order the item (display a message).

What I have is leaving out the last bit. I know it is something simple.

```
cost=int(input("Please Enter The Cost Of The Item You Wish To Purchase: "))
if cost>5000:
    print("Your Must Go To Tender")
elif cost<=500 or cost<=5000:
   print("Your Must Get 3 Different Quotes")
else:
    print("You May Order")
```

Comment: Yes it is something simple.  Look **carefully** at this statement `elif cost<=500 or cost<=5000:`

Comment: The second case should be `cost >= 500 or cost <= 5000` (or more naturally, `500 <= cost <= 5000`.

Comment: @chepner - Your correction is not correct.  Consider what the OP is actually trying to do in that test .....

Comment: Please debug the conditions individually in python shell before posting such questions.

Comment: @StephenC How so?

Comment: @StephenC Are you misreading my comment?

Comment: Ah, I'm misreading my comment :)

Comment: There's no problem with the more Pythonic chained comparison, though.

Comment: Eh, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

That's because of your `elif`condition which should be:

```
elif cost >= 500 and cost <= 5000:
```